# theme table from drupal 6 to drupal 7

Tags: theming

I try to rewrite the node output and i don`t get it. This script produce only

```
<table></table>
```

without any content.

```
$rows = array();
$cols = array();

$cols[] = '<div id="node-title">' . $node->title[0]['value'] . '</div>';

$colnum = 0;

foreach($node->field_body as $col){
  $colnum++;
  $cols[] = '<div class="description" id="description-' . $colnum . '">' . $col['value'] . '</div>';
}

$rows[] = array('data' => $cols);

print theme('table', $rows)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables to theme functions must be named:

```
print theme('table', array('rows' => $rows));
```

See [the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) for more details.

Comment: thx! now, it works!